# I want to change the image every time I tap the button

Tags: swift3, uiimageview, uibutton, swift2, uiimage

I want to change the image every time I tap a button.
The name of the image is as follows.
1. png
2. png
3. png
4. png
The name of the button is addButton.
Currently, each time you tap addButton, the image switches as follows.
1. png → 2. png → 3. png → 4. png → 1. png → 2. png → 3. png → loop ....
The code is as follows.

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var imageNum: Int = 0
        var imageArray:[UIImage] = []
        var stampImage = UIImage(named: "1")!
        var stampView:UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
        //@IBOutlet weak var reduceButton: UIButton!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()
              for i in 1...4 {
                    imageArray.append(UIImage(named: "\(i).png")!)
              }
              stampView = UIImageView(image: imageArray[0])
              stampView.center = self.view.center
        }
        @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

              imageNum = (imageNum + 1) % imageArray.count
              stampView.image = imageArray[imageNum]
              stampImage = UIImage(named: "\(imageNum + 1)")!
        }
  }
```

Next, when you tap reduceButton, you want to display one image back.
For example, 
if the currently displayed image is 2.png,
you want to display reduceButton as follows for each tap.
2. png → 1. png → 4. png → 3. png → 2. png → 1. png → 4. png → 3. png → loop...

What kind of coding should I do in such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same with subtracting one instead of adding it to the `imageNum` like that:

```
imageNum = (imageNum - 1) % imageArray.count
```

But since `imageNum` can get negative it would be safer to add `imageArray.count` to the expression in parenthesis so the final line would look like:

```
imageNum = (imageArray.count + imageNum - 1) % imageArray.count
```

By adding the `imageArray.count` we are preventing the modulus operation to run on a negative variable while also maintaining the correct cycling between all numbers due to a fact that adding any multiplier of a number on rhs of modulo operation does not affect the the result of an expression

Comment: I was worried a few days after an error was displayed.
It started to work without problems.
Thank you for your comment.